# T-SQL SELECT * is Fast, SELECT TOP 50 is Slow

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

(Deleted previous post, may be it wasn't asked the right way, I'll try again)

```
    -- 300Ms
    SELECT AppId FROM Application ap
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MissingThings mt on mt.AppId = ap.AppId
    WHERE mt.AppId is NULL
    ORDER BY mt.Id

-- 1.5s
SELECT TOP 50 FROM (TheSame)

    -- 100Ms
    SELECT TOP 50 AppId FROM Application ap
    LEFT OUTER JOIN MissingThings mt on mt.AppId = ap.AppId
    --WHERE mt.AppId is NULL
    ORDER BY mt.Id
```

If I apply TOP on the original query, it gets slow. If no TOP, it returns all 1000 records fast.

If I remove the WHERE clause and have the TOP 50, it is again fast.

Also tried as other posts suggest to replace the WHERE with NOT EXISTS. Didn't help.

Are there any general possible causes or it is really specific to my database?
If it is specific I guess, I can't expect help here, because I am not allowed to share Execution Plans.

EDIT:

There were 2 other conditions in the WHERE clause, which I thought were really neglect-able,but once I commented those, the original query returns in 50ms!!!!!!!

```
SELECT TOP 50 AppId FROM Application ap
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MissingThings mt on mt.AppId = ap.AppId
        WHERE mt.AppId is NULL
AND ap.IsOrderFinished = 1
AND ap.IsAssigned = 2
        ORDER BY mt.Id
```

Added non-clustered index on IsOrderFinished and on IsAssigned  - no help with Both or either one of the indexes.

More results:

Descending order by is fast (50ms!)
`ORDER BY mt.Id DESC` (go figure)

Comment: what index do you have on table Application? do you have a dedicated index for the AppId column?

Comment: AppID is PKey and it is clustered index on Application table.

Comment: This could be a problem with outdated statistics causing a cardinality mismatch, but only the execution plans could confirm that. If you can't share them (not even after anonymizing all the names?) it gets difficult. Updating statistics of both tables won't hurt, in any case. Neither will indexing `MissingThings.AppId`, if that's not already the case.

Comment: First of all, I would suggest to change the where clause so you do is null against the table's PKey

Comment: @lakta, I need to get only those records that have no matching in that JOIN. If I do it on the PKey it will return nothing? Or I am missing something. So AppId is always there on the primary table, but that WHERE filters the records that do not have corresponding ones in the second table.

Comment: Are the datatypes of both tables AppID identical?

Comment: @st_stefanov, i hope i can clarify myself with an exemple: `select * from TabA a left outer join TabB b on b.FKey =  a.PKey where b.PKey is null`

Comment: @DaveBrown - BINGO, they are not identical. PKey is BIGINT, Fkey is INT, NULL. Does that help?

Comment: @lakta, perfect, thanks. I did that, WHERE mt.PKeyColumn = null - sorry, but no difference.

Comment: @JeroenMostert - how do I anonymize all the names?

Comment: Laborious search/replace, I'm afraid. If you're using tables and not views, the number of recognizable names involved in the query plans should be limited. Otherwise, it's a bit more work -- but if you're using a view that completely changes the game anyway, because it represents a (hidden) query itself that's rather crucial in the whole affair! The optimizer effectively expands the view definition inside the query and optimizes the whole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some times I can't make work optimally a full query, but I can make optimal their parts. Then instead of keep trying to optimize the full query, I just move the parts to a temporal table and use them to construct the full query.

This should execute in 300ms instead of 1.5s

```
SELECT AppId 
into #Application
FROM Application ap
     LEFT OUTER JOIN MissingThings mt on mt.AppId = ap.AppId
WHERE mt.AppId is NULL
ORDER BY ap.AppId 

SELECT TOP 50 * FROM #Application

DROP TABLE #Application
```

We cam also try to speed it up a bit, using your fastest query. This should execute in closer to 100ms.

```
CREATE TABLE #Application (AppId INT, MissingAppId INT)
CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX #IX_Application ON #Application (MissingAppId, AppId)

INSERT INTO #Application (AppId, MissingAppId)
SELECT ap.AppId, mt.AppId
FROM Application ap
     LEFT OUTER JOIN MissingThings mt on mt.AppId = ap.AppId

SELECT TOP 50 * 
FROM #Application
WHERE MissingAppId IS NULL
ORDER BY AppId

DROP TABLE #Application
```

Comment: Good idea. I was thinking of a way to pull all of them and then perform my sorting, topping...let's see if that helps.

Comment: @st_stefanov let me know if it works, because if it does, we can use the same principle to try to run it on the 100ms of your fastest query.

Comment: @st_stefanov the drop #Application has to be drop table #Application. I have updated the anser. Do you mean that or there is some other error ?, in that case, please share the error message.

Comment: I had issues to fit the nested select, but I used SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM MyViewName...and that worked. It is fast, but it takes 600ms (not 300ms)

Comment: Or may be that was temporary DB load and it returns for the same time...That can be used as a workaround, but I do want to find the reason behind that slow performance.

Comment: @st_stefanov I have added a new option based on your fastest query. Why don't you try to see if it is faster ?.

Comment: @st_stefanov yes, of course, check the execution plan and see where the problem is. But sometimes, specially with complex queries, the engine fails to calculate the optimal plan. Using this workaround you can force it to run the query the way you want it.

Comment: For execution plan analysis, I recomend [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://www.sentryone.com/plan-explorer), it is free. I'm using it at work

Comment: EDITED my post. Sorry, I must have missed the importance of these in the WHERE clause.

Comment: @MarcGuillot, what you suggest seems to be the best approach that I got so far. Could you tell me how to make a new View to call my slow view as you suggested? In the end I need to call that from EF/C# and apply paging (.Skip(1).Take(50)...)

Comment: @st_stefanov: A view cannot create temporary tables or materialize another view. You'll need a stored procedure for that. Alternatively, you can try if `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` prevents the optimizer from expanding the joins in a sub-optimal way, although hints like that should be used as a last resort. Note that adding paging will itself add another way for things to become slow, as paging these results is inherently inefficient (`.Skip(1000).Take(50)` will essentially still make the server generate 1000 rows to ignore before getting the next 50).

Comment: Yeah, I guess that is why I wanted to find the "heart" of this issue...